# VBA Access - Multiple Tables count by date

Tags: ms-access, vba

We'd like to count from an Access database that has multiple tables - about 50.

We need to count from 1 column in each table that is 'QCPASS'  This is a check box - if a product passed the box was checked if failed then not. We need to count both for EACH table, also allowing the user to specify a date range from a date column that exists in every table.

I've tried this with a query but I am told the query is unable to select, count and do the date range. Any VBA help would be great.

Exporting to Excel would be great, but any results would be fine. Here is the query I created that counts in a column from each table passes and failures. I can't iterate with a query either, so VBA seems the way to go:

```
SELECT "Table1" , Count('qcpass') AS column 
FROM 5000028 
GROUP BY [5000028].qcpass
union 
SELECT "Table2",count('qcpass')
FROM 5000029 
Group By [5000029].qcpass;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse the full `TableDefs` collection in your database, and create a query using VBA.

**A word of warning:** The `TableDefs` collection has the Access database system tables, so you need to skip this. A way I suggest you is to check for a specific table name prefix (it is noted in the code below).

```vb
public sub createMyBigUnionQuery()
dim db as DAO.database(), tbl as DAO.tableDef
dim strSQL as string, i as integer
set db = currentdb()
i = 1
for each tbl in db.TableDefs
    if left(tbl.name, 1) = "5" then ' Check for a table name prefix
        if i = 1 then
            ' The final spaces are important
            strSQL = "select '" & tbl.Name & "' as table, count(qcpass) as column " & _
                     "from [" & tbl.Name & "] " & _
                     "group by qcpass "
        else
            ' The final spaces are important
            strSQL = strSQL & " union all " & _
                     "select '" & tbl.Name & "' as table, count(qcpass) as column " & _
                     "from [" & tbl.Name & "] " & _
                     "group by qcpass "
        end if
        i = i + 1
    end if
next tbl
db.createQueryDef "qryYourFinalQuery", strSQL
db.close
exit sub
```

Notice that you can define *any* valid query you want. Take this as a hint, and tweak it to fit your specific needs.

Hope this helps you

---

Adressing @HansUp comment, if you need to filter your data by date, you have two options:

1. Include the `where` condition on every `select` created by the procedure
2. Include the date field in your query and group by it, and create a second query to filter the data you need from the created query.

I would personally go with option 1, and here is a sample code:

```vb
public sub createMyBigUnionQueryWithDates(d0 as date, d1 as date)
dim db as DAO.database(), tbl as DAO.tableDef
dim strSQL as string, i as integer
set db = currentdb()
i = 1
for each tbl in db.TableDefs
    if left(tbl.name, 1) = "5" then ' Check for a table name prefix
        if i = 1 then
            ' The final spaces are important
            strSQL = "select '" & tbl.Name & "' as table, count(qcpass) as column " & _
                     "from [" & tbl.Name & "] " & _
                     "where rowDate between " & cDbl(d0) & " and " &cDbl(d1) & " " & _
                     "group by qcpass "
        else
            ' The final spaces are important
            strSQL = strSQL & " union all " & _
                     "select '" & tbl.Name & "' as table, count(qcpass) as column " & _
                     "from [" & tbl.Name & "] " & _
                     "where rowDate between " & cDbl(d0) & " and " &cDbl(d1) & " " & _
                     "group by qcpass "
        end if
        i = i + 1
    end if
next tbl
db.createQueryDef "qryYourOtherFinalQuery", strSQL
db.close
exit sub
```

The reason I use `cDbl(d0)` is because Access dates are sensitive to regional settings, and I've had a lot of headaches dealing with it. Access (and many other Microsoft products) store dates as floating-point numbers (the integer part is the date, and the decimal part is the time).

**Another word of warning:** If your dates don't include time, then the `between` condition will work. But if they do include time, then I recommend you change the where condition to this:

```
"where rowDate >= " & cDbl(d0) & " and rowDate < " & cDbl(d1 + 1)"
```

Comment: This answer ignores the "count by date" part of the question.

Comment: @HansUp It shouldn't be hard to write the appropriate fields, `where` conditions and `group by` criteria in the query, don't you think?

Comment: Not really, but in a previous question OP said he does not want to write a `WHERE` for each of the 50 `SELECT`s he is unioning together.

Comment: @HansUp I've edited the question to adress your comment. And I think the `where` condition in every select is the easiest way to go (*this* post says nothing about not wanting `where`s on every select). Anyway, this is just *one way* to do it, and it works.

Comment: @HansUp I've read the previous question from the OP... I think he didn't want to write a where condition "by hand" on every single select. By using VBA code the effort is minimal.

Comment: Thanks Greatly Barranka. The first solution seems to return:union all select 'QT6000' as table, count(qcpass) as coulumn from [QT6000] group by qcpass only

Comment: @user2543597 Sorry, I forgot to add `strSQL = strSQL & " ..."` Just made the correction.

Comment: It now returns: SELECT '5000222-06' as table, count(qcpass) as coulumn from [5000222-06] group by qcpass           and then a long list of FALSE

Comment: @user2543597 Debug it: Execute it step by step and check on every step the value of `strSQL`. The program should build the query step by step. I don't see any reason for the `False` values to be generated.

Comment: Ok, My immediate problem is why is access treating the: strSQL =     "SELECT '" & tbl.Name & "' as table, count(qcpass) as coulumn " & _
                     "from [" & tbl.Name & "] " & _
                     "group by qcpass "              as a string outputting: SELECT '5000222-06' as table, count(qcpass) as coulumn from [5000222-06] group by qcpass

Comment: @user2543597 Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Its not outputting a count of QCPASS - Its just outputting whats in quotes like here. The only thing its processing is the table name - SELECT '5000222-06' as table, count(qcpass) as coulumn from [5000222-06] group by qcpass –

Comment: Im learning about merging VBA and access. As far as I understand, Access should be treating the count and select in quotes as actual commands, not string type characters - which debug.print is spitting out

Comment: @user2543597 The `strSQL` variable stores the SQL instruction that will create the query. When the instruction is built, `db.createQueryDef "qryYourQuery", strSQL` will create a query object with the SQL instruction built. When it is done, you can open the query in your database. Remember: **Query objects are simply SQL instructions stored in your database**, not "real" datasets. This piece of code won't output any data... it will create the query you need

Comment: I see. So I wouldnt be able to place a debug.print - and see results from this? Or - results from debug.print will be different than the saved query?

Comment: @user2543597 You can copy the `Debug.print` result and paste it in an empty query object to see if it is working. The query is created at the end of the procedure anyway. Once it is created, you can open it from your database objects list (the main MS Access window).

Comment: Lol, All it does is inject the string into the query - I just wasnt seeing that. Thanks - youve been an amazing help

Comment: @user2543597 I suggest you get your hands on a good Access book. I use a (very old) one, by John Viescas... but Access hasn't changed a lot since 1997 ;) (access files can be bigger, and there are some new VBA tricks, but the essential things remain unchanged)

Comment: @user2543597 by the way... if this worked for you, up-vote it and/or accept it ;-)

Comment: on final question Barranka - How do I get the column name in that Date string? Do I use DAO.Field?

Comment: @user2543597 I used `rowDate` as a placeholder... you should write the name of the field in your table(s). If every table has different field names, you may need to use a `DAO.RecordSet` object to get the field name.